# how to click on treeviewnode to download a file

Tags: asp.net, treeview, treenode

I want to list files on a treeview and if I click on a treenode (a file), that file will be downloaded:

```
<asp:TreeView Id="MyTree" 
                      PathSeparator = "|"
                      OnTreeNodePopulate="PopulateNode"
                      ExpandDepth="0"
                      runat="server" ImageSet="XPDirectoryListing" NodeIndent="15">

            <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5"></SelectedNodeStyle>
            <NodeStyle VerticalPadding="2" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalPadding="2" ForeColor="#000000"></NodeStyle>
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA"></HoverNodeStyle>

            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Demos" PopulateOnDemand="True" Value="Demos" />
            </Nodes>

        </asp:TreeView>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class DirectoryListing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void PopulateNode(Object source, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = e.Node;

        if (e.Node.Value == "Demos")
        {
            e.Node.Value = Server.MapPath("~/");
        }

        String[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(node.Value);

        // Enumerate directories
        foreach (String dir in dirs)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(dir), dir);

            if (Directory.GetFiles(dir).Length > 0 || Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length > 0)
            {
                newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            }

            node.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        }

        // Enumerate files
        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(node.Value);

        foreach (String file in files)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(file), file);
            node.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change it such a way that I click on a treenode, the file at the treenode will be downloaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is an intranet app, then this might work:

```
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(file), file);
            newNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
            newNode.NavigateUrl = Path.GetFullPath(file);
            node.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
```

If it's not an intranet app you could hook on to the selectedNodeChanged event on the treeview and use a file streamer to stream the file to the client. But you most likely have to specify the MIME type of the file depending on what files you plan to send.

Comment: OK, so it is not an internet app? Then the code above could work if the user hass access rights to the path of the file. If the user does not have access you'll either have to give them access or use a file streamer to serve the file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to turn the tree nodes into links. Once you have the link capture the onclick javascript event and in that event add an iframe to the page that has the address of the file. This will cause the file to be downloaded.

Comment: because the location is configurable in code-behind so I dont think using Jquery is a good approach?

Comment: Once the information gets to the client you aren't configuring it any more. You can put enough information out to the client that you can use javascript to generate links that will download your files. I think the solution above would be more to your liking.